# How Does Identity Work in Asp .Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

Say, I have a SQL Server Database containing usernames/passwords.  At my "login" view, I wish to enter data into the username/password text fields and when I click "login" I want to use my login Controller to compare those values against the values in the Database.  All of that is fairly straight forward:
[image]

However, I want to use the `[Authorize]` Attribute on the remainder of my site's Controllers.  After granted access past the Login page, I can't seem to find any examples that explain how to "Authorize" a user so that the `["Authorize"]` Attributes recognize this user and allows them to access other Controllers/Actions. Here is how I have begun to set this up, but I can't find any direction on where to take it from here.

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    // GET: /<controller>/
    //[Route("/Login")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public bool Login(Workflow.Models.WorkflowContext wfc, string username, string password)
    {
        var user = wfc.User.Where(u => u.Active && u.Username == username && u.Password == password).ToList();
        if (user.Count > 0)
        {               
            //User may log in
            return true;
        }
        else
            //Access Denied
            return false;
    }
}
```

For instance, without a user being authorized, I do not want them to be able to reach my "Home Controller":

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{ 
    [Route("/Home")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Error()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I have been hearing about the classes "Identity" and "SignInManager" and I am a bit overwhelmed on how to use either of those options.  I am still somewhat new to ASP .Net MVC, so I am trying to get a grasp on how Authorization works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Authentication/authorization is *much* more complicated than simply verifying a username and password one time. ASP.NET Identity is one of a few different mechanisms available to ASP.NET apps to handle authentication/authorization, and is the recommended approach for individual user auth. It replaces the *much* older ASP.NET Membership. `SignInManager` is just a class that's part of ASP.NET Identity that handles things like signing a user in (obviously). It is not some separate thing.

With that out of the way, you're going to just have to dig in. You definitely don't want to try to create your own system from scratch, and going forward, Identity is pretty much the primary method of authentication and authorization within ASP.NET. Learn it now, and you'll be able to work with the largest majority of ASP.NET sites out there and you'll be able to apply your knowledge to any new ASP.NET site you create.

Start your journey at https://www.asp.net/identity. There's a number of good tutorials and guides listed there and linked to from there (make sure to check out the additional resources). Also, you'll want to create a new MVC project with Individual User Accounts selected. This will give you a scaffolded project with basic Identity stuff baked in. You can also go whole hog and create a blank MVC project and then install the Identity Samples Nuget package. This will create a scaffolded project with pretty much every feature in Identity (two-factor auth, third-party OAuth logins, etc.). With that you can get a good idea of how everything works.

Comment: Thank you.  I figured it wasn't as simple as just comparing values in a SQL Table.  The best solution is just to jump in and try to understand everything, I suppose.  I have looked into that link already and was curious if it was really that complicated, I guess.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Well, it's not really complicated, but I could see "overwhelming". There's a lot of information to absorb, for sure. However, you can always just start small and expand later. Focus of just get a simple sign in, then add password reset, account management, etc. Then, you can start looking at third-party logins and/or two-factor auth.

Comment: Overwhelming is a great way to put it haha.  That was my plan, basically develop more "account management" type functionality after I understood how the actual logins were handled.  Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{
   

    SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager {  get; set; }
    UserManager<AppUser> _userManager { get; set; }
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager {  get; set; }
    public AuthController(SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager, UserManager<AppUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult>Register(RegisterVm vm)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(vm);
        }
        var user = new AppUser()
        {
            Email = vm.Email,
            Surname = vm.Surname,
            Name = vm.Name,
            UserName = vm.Username
        };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user,vm.Password);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                return View();
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult>Login(string? returnUrl,LoginVm vm)
    {
        AppUser user;
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(vm);
        }
        if (vm.UsernameorEmail.Contains("@"))
        {
            user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(vm.UsernameorEmail);
        }
        else
        {
            user= await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(vm.UsernameorEmail);
        }
        if(user != null) 
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, vm.Password, vm.isRemember, true);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Login attempt");
                return View();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login Not Found");
            return View();
        }
        if (returnUrl != null)
        {
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    public async Task<bool> CreateRoles()
    {
        foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Roles)))
        {
            if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(item.ToString()))
            {
                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole
                {
                    Name = item.ToString(),
                });
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).